# How to make a biased random number generator in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, random

**How do I make a biased random number generator (RNG) in VB.NET?**

I know I could make it by fiddling with the output of the `Randomize()`/`Rnd` methods, but is there a built-in way of doing this?

I want the biased RNG to give me **either** a 2 or 4 (though using 1 or 2 as a substitute is also OK by me), with 2 occurring on average 90% of the time and 4 occurring on average 10% of the time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is what I think you can do.

```
 Dim numbers() as integer = {2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,2,2} ' set 10% for 4, 90% for 2
 Dim r as new Random()
 Return numbers(r.Next(0, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a random number generator to return values from 1-10, if the value from the random number generator is between 1 and 9 send a 2 if the value is 10 send a 4.

You might want to look at this

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ctssatww(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ctssatww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

If you want to come out with a mask to generate your values

Comment: thanks for volunteering an answer! However I said "**built-in**" method and so this isn't exactly what i wanted. I won't downvote you though out of kindness.